# One-liner or short script to run the code inside a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

I like to develop scripts by running them piecemeal in a Jupyter (nee iJulia) notebook.  However, sometimes I need to test things on a remote system and need to make a copy of just the code as a .jl file.  Has anyone already written a one-liner or short script that runs the code in a .ipynb notebook?  If not, I'll get to it at some point and post the code here.

Comment: From the notebook, is `File -> Download as -> Julia(txt)` adequate?

Comment: That's what I've been doing, although I would like some way to just run the code without having to save it as a separate file -- something like "julia parser.jl notebook.ipnb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I have written up:

```
using JSON

get_code_cells(j::Dict) = filter(x->x["cell_type"] == "code", j["cells"])

function parse_code_cell(c::Dict)
    buf = IOBuffer()
    write(buf, "begin\n")
    map(x->write(buf, x), c["source"])
    write(buf, "\nend")

    src = bytestring(buf)
    parse(src)
end

extract_code(cells::Vector) = Expr[parse_code_cell(c) for c in cells]
extract_code(j::Dict) = extract_code(get_code_cells(j))
eval_code(j::Dict) = map(eval, extract_code(j))


# get filename, then parse to json, then run all code
const fn = ARGS[1]
eval_code(JSON.parsefile(fn))
```

It seems to work for many notebooks, but not everything. Specifically, it failed to run a notebook where I had

```
using PyCall
@pyimport seaborn as sns
```

When `eval` hit that chunk of code it complained about `@pyimport` not being defined (even though it is exported by `PyCall`).

If you are interested, we could definitely clean this up, add some more arguments and package it up into a proper command line utility.

---

## EDIT

Now for something completely different...

This version shells out to `ipython nbconvert`, writes that to a temporary file, calls `include` on that temporary file to run the code, then deletes the temp file. This should be more robust (it passed examples the other one failed at). Same comments about cleaning/packaging apply.

```
const fn = abspath(ARGS[1])
dir = dirname(fn)

# shell out to nbconvert to get a string with code
src = readall(`ipython nbconvert --to script --stdout $fn`)

# Generate random filenamein this directory, write code string to it
script_fn = joinpath(dir, string(randstring(30), ".jl"))
open(script_fn, "w") do f
    write(f, src)
end

# now try to run the file we just write. We do this so we can make sure
# to get to the call `rm(script_fn)` below.
try
    include(script_fn)
catch
    warn("Failed executing script from file")
end

# clean up by deleting the temporary file we created
rm(script_fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Julia package [NBInclude.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/NBInclude.jl) makes this easy:

```
using NBInclude
@nbinclude("myfile.ipynb")
```

Runs the whole notebook and returns the value of the last cell evaluated.